# How to get variation IDs of custom list items in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, variations

In sharepoint 2013, I know I can get page or site variations using the getpeerurl method something like this

```
function GetOtherUrl(link, success, fail) {
    var other_culture = _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName === "en-US" ? "fr-fr" : "en-us";
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(link);
    var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, link, other_culture);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(object, success), Function.createDelegate(object, fail));
}
```

however, for items on custom lists which also have variations enabled, how can I get the ID of the other language item? I can't assume it will be the same ID because if I manually create an item in the other language list and delete it, then that messes up the id consistency, however sharepoint still somehow tracks it.

Anyone know a way to find out the correct id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getPeerUrl()` returns the Server-Relative URL of the requested Variation.  This is good, because you can then turn around and call 'getFileByServerRelativeUrl()' to get a reference to the File Object.  If you need to the metadata, you get use the File Object's `get_listItemAllFields()` method.  Here is an example:

```
function getOtherUrl(link, success, fail) {
    var other_culture = _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName === "en-US" ? "fr-fr" : "en-us";
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(link);
    var peerUrl = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, link, other_culture);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(peerUrl);
      }, 
      fail
   );
}

function getFileProperties(url,success,fail) {

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var relUrl = url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,'');  //convert to relative url
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);   //get file
   ctx.load(file,'ListItemAllFields'); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(file);
      }, 
      fail
   );
}

function errorHandler(sender,args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}

function doSomethingWithVariationItem(originalLink) {
    getOtherUrl(originalLink, 
        function(peerUrl) {
            getFileProperties(peerUrl, 
                function(file) {
                    var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
                    console.log("The variation's Item ID is " + listItem.Id);
                    // do something with file or listItem or Id here 
                }
            )
        },
        errorHandler
    );

}
```

Comment: but how does this apply to a custom list item? Your code seems to be still for pages...

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize SharePoint supported Variations of list items.  I have only ever used it for pages.